# Prove $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x^{n}=0$

Tags: real-analysis

I would like to know if my proof is valid, because I did it different from the solution in my textbook (which uses Bernoulli's inequality).

If $|x|<1$, then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x^{n}=0$.

*Proof*

For $x=0$ it is trivial, so we suppose that $0<|x|<1$. Let $N>\dfrac{\log(x\varepsilon)}{\log(x)}$, then
\begin{align*}
|x|^{n}<x^{n}\frac{1}{x}<\varepsilon
\end{align*}
implies that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x^{n}=0$ when $|x|<1$.

Comment: But $|x|^n\le x^nx$ is false for $0\lt|x|\lt1$.

Comment: Oops. Ofcourse. So is it more correct now ?

Comment: What happens if $x$ is negative? Your proof isn't quite correct yet.

Comment: Ye, I just noticed that myself. I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Wow, - I don't know how that happened. Sorry.

Comment: Still, do you know what the logarithm is? The reason to use Bernoulli's inequality is exactly that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\;0<x<1\;$ , and I'll let you do the minor modifications for the case $\,-1<x<0\;$ . First, write

$$x=\frac1r\;,\;\;1<r\in\Bbb R\;,\;\;\text{and now prove that}\;\;r^n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\infty\;\ldots$$

Hint for the last part: assume it is false and use the archimedean property of the reals...